# DB Access denied

Tags: sql, wamp, connect

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\connect.php on line 6
```

I've looked for a solution but haven't been able to find one.
The part on line 6 is
`mysql_connect($server,$username,$password)`

If it has to do with the problem, I'm using WampServer 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users `admin@%` and `admin@localhost` can have different passwords in MySQL.  Try without a password.

Check the contents of the mysql.user table to see if your have multiple user records for admin.

This is a nice access model which allows different access depending on server the user is connecting from.

Comment: Apparently without a password works. I guess I'll have to set one.

Answer (score 0):

username/password combination should be incorrect.
You must have been prompted to set the password while installing WAMP Server.
You sure you are using the same password?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the root password by executing the following statement int the command line:-

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

If it complains `mysqladmin` is not a recognized command, then navigate to `<WAMP-FOLDER>/mysql/bin` folder before executing that statement.